# putPixel with ImageJ

Tags: java, imagej

I'm an ImageJ beginner, and I'm trying to use putPixel without much success.

```
ImagePlus ip = IJ.getImage();
    HistogramWindow histo = new HistogramWindow(ip);
    int w = ip.getWidth(), h = ip.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[4];
    int[] pxltmp = {0,0,0};
    int temp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            pixels = (int[])ip.getPixel(i,j);
            pxltmp[0] = pixels[2];
            pxltmp[1] = pixels[1];
            pxltmp[2] = pixels[0];
            **ip.putPixel(i,j,pxltmp);**
        }
    }
```

My plugin breaks at this line, I'm trying to send putPixel an x,y, and an array of three pixels.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, is there any better way to get error messages in ImageJ, I'm in the dark for now.  I tried setting up eclipse but having issues there.

Comment: What's the error message/stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ip` variable is an `ImagePlus` and doesn't have a `putPixel()` method. Get the `ImageProcessor` first, then it should work.

```
ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
ImageProcessor ip = imp.getProcessor();
ip.putPixel(x,y,value);
```

It looks like you just want to transform RGB to BGR. This can be done a lot simpler using ImageJ commands:

```
IJ.run(imp, "RGB Stack", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Reverse", "");
IJ.run("Stack to RGB", "");
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer, you may be able to help me out with something else.  Whenever I get errors there's no information, no window popup or anything.  The only way I can tell I have an error is that the file never compiled, or that some print statements didn't appear in the log.  How do I enable those popups?

Comment: New questions are best asked using the `Ask Question` button. This also allows you detail how you're running the commands/plugins, and which version of ImageJ/Fiji you're using, some essential information to be able to answer your question.